# What does $K^{m \times m}$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

$K^{m \times m}$ is unclear to me. I know what $K^{m}$ means. I know what $K_{m}$ means.
My guess ist that $K^{m \times m}$ is the set of all quadratic matrices. May someone confirm that?

Comment: You mean all $m \times n$ matrices with values in a field $K$? If so then that sounds reasonble.

Comment: More likely the set of $m \times n$ matrices over $K$.

Comment: Guys I am so sorry I made a mistake when writing the question. Now the exponent is $mxm$ instead of $mxn$ ($mxn$ before the edit was unintended, just me being unattentive...)

Comment: If $K^m$ is the vectors of length $m$ over the field $K$, what is $K_m$?

Comment: According to my textbook, if I understood correctly, $K_{m}$ describes the set of tuples with m entries over the field K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I would infer that $K^{m \times m}$ means 'the set of all $m \times m$ matrices over the field$^{[1]}$ $K$'.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1):

The notation $K^{m\times n}$ usually means the set of all $m\times n$ matrices over a commutative ring $K$. It is also denoted by $M_{m,n}(K)$. Both notations are (practically) standard.

When $m=n$, the matrices has $m$ rows and $m$ columns. Hence the notation means the set of all square matrices of order $m$ over $K$. It is also denoted by $M_m(K)$.

When $n=1$, $K^{m\times n}$ is identified with $K^m$, the $m$-fold Cartesian product of $K$. It is also viewed as the set of all column vectors of with $m$ entries in $K$.

(In contrast, the use of the notation $K_m$ to mean all $m$-tuples of elements in $K$ is neither standard nor common in linear algebra literature.)